# I'm confused... What exactly are 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit forms?

Tags: swift, binary, int

I am newer to programming and I've been reading [The Swift Programming Language](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH5-ID309). In their paragraph on integers I saw something about 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit forms:

> Swift provides signed and unsigned integers in 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit forms.

I am a little confused about what they are.
The book also mentioned something about those bit forms having minimum and maximum values:

> You can access the minimum and maximum values of each integer type with its min and max properties

Thanks!

Comment: Please quote the statements which are unclear to you. *"I saw something about ..."* and *"The book also mentioned something ..."* is pretty vague.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you're talking about `Int` and `UInt` in it's different forms.

First off you have to understand how values are stored in computers. You probably have heard of [binary](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_code) representation. There's a lot that can be discussed on the topic, but here's a short explaination:

We normally use decimal numbers. This means that you can use ten different digits (`0` to `9`) in each column (`1s`, `10s`, `100s`...). Therefore the number of values that can be represented in decimal is given by `10` to the power of the number of columns.
If you have only two colums, you can represent `00` to `99`, so `100` different values, or `10²`.

Now aside from decimal there are other number systems. The main difference is their *base*. Decimal is also called *base-10*, because it has ten different digits.
Binary is also called *base-2*, meaning there are only two digits: `0` and `1`.

Due to this limitation in digits we also are limited on the number of different values that can be represented for a given number of columns. With two columns we were able to represent `10²` values in *base-10*. So in *base-2* we can represent `2²` values: `0` to `3`, or in binary `00` to `11`.

For a more in-depth explaination check this [video](https://youtu.be/LpuPe81bc2w) out.

Now the forms (`8`, `16`, `32`...) of `Int`s refer to the number of columns.
`Int`s are of course stored in memory. And since memory is finite, the number of columns, or *bits*, an `Int` is allowed to use is limited. The values `8`, `16`, `32`, etc. are these number of bits, which are used by the `Int`. And as a result of this limitation `Int`s can only store a range of numbers according to their number of bits.

So a `UInt8` has `8` bits, therefore `8` columns, and can store `2^8` values: `0` to `255`.
An `Int32` has `32` bits and can store `2^32` values: `-2,147,483,648` to `2,147,483,647`.

Now the difference between `Int` and `UInt` is simple. `Int` can represent positive and negative numbers, while `UInt` can only represent non-negatives (so everything greater or equal to `0`).

I'm not going to explain negative binary numbers. If you're interested though check out [Two's Complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two%27s_complement).